# Informacion de un TableView a un fichero y viceversa

Tags: javafx

estoy realizando un ejercicio en JavaFX11, donde mi intención es almacenar información en un TableView y mediante un botón Guardar, lea todos los datos de mi TableView y los almacene en un fichero.

También busco que mi aplicación sea capaz de leer ese fichero y cargue los datos de él y los añada al TableView.
No intento que me hagais las dos funciones que me quedan, solo pido que me intenteis guiar de como leer los datos almacenados y que sea el fichero capaz de almacenenarlos de tal forma que luego sea capaz de insertarlos en un TableView.

Os dejo aquí lo que llevo hecho de programa, como vereis, los botones demás de Añadir,Borrar,Modificar y Limpiar funcionan correctamente, el de Guardar y Abrir no.

```
package ejerciciosJavaFx;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView.TableViewSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class tableView extends Application {
  TableView<Contact> tableView = new TableView<Contact>();
  String nombre, apellido, telefono;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // In order to use a JavaFX TableView component you must first create a TableView instance
    

    /*
     * Having created a TableView you need to add one or more TableColumn instances to the 
     * TableView instance. 
     * 
     * A TableColumn represents a vertical column of values. 
     * 
     * Each value is displayed on its own row, and is typically extracted from the list of objects 
     * being displayed in the TableView.
     */

    TableColumn<Contact, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
    TableColumn<Contact, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
    TableColumn<Contact, String> column3 = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    TableColumn<Contact, String> column4 = new TableColumn<>("Phone");

    /*
     * A TableColumn must have a cell value factory set on it. 
     * 
     * The cell value factory extracts the value to be displayed in each cell (on each row) in the 
     * column. 
     * 
     * The PropertyValueFactory factory can extract a property value (field value) from a Java object. 
     * 
     * The name of the property is passed as a parameter to the PropertyValueFactory constructor.
     */

    column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
    column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
    column3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    column4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("phoneNumber"));

    // Add columns
    tableView.getColumns().add(column1);
    tableView.getColumns().add(column2);
    tableView.getColumns().add(column3);
    tableView.getColumns().add(column4);

    /*
     * You can set a placeholder to be displayed when the JavaFX TableView has no rows to display. 
     * 
     * The placeholder must be an instance of the JavaFX Node class, which most (if not all) JavaFX 
     * controls are. 
     */

    tableView.setPlaceholder(new Label("No rows to display"));

    /*
     * Once you have added TableColumn instances to the JavaFX TableView, you can add the data 
     * to be displayed to the TableView. 
     */

    tableView.getItems().add(new Contact("John", "Doe", "666111222"));
    tableView.getItems().add(new Contact("Jane", "Deer", "666111222"));
    tableView.getItems().add(new Contact("Mike", "Scot", "666111222"));
    tableView.getItems().add(new Contact("Lucy", "Bonn", "666111222"));
    tableView.getItems().add(new Contact("Pepe", "Bond", "666111222"));

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

    // To obtain a list of the row items of a JavaFX TableView, you call getItems() method. 

    Button buttonPrint = new Button("Print Table");
    buttonPrint.setOnAction(e -> {
      for (Contact contact : tableView.getItems()) {
        textArea.appendText(contact + "\n");
      }
      textArea.appendText("---\n");
    });

    /*
     * The JavaFX TableView component has an internal SelectionModel which is used to either read 
     * what rows and / or cells the user has selected, or to select rows and cells programmatically
     */

    TableViewSelectionModel<Contact> selectionModel = tableView.getSelectionModel();

    // set selection mode to only 1 row (default)
    selectionModel.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);

    // You can set selection mode to multiple rows

    Button buttonSelection = new Button("Multiple Selection");
    buttonSelection.setOnAction(e -> {
      if (selectionModel.getSelectionMode().equals(SelectionMode.SINGLE)) {
        selectionModel.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        buttonSelection.setText("Single Selection");
      } else {
        selectionModel.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        buttonSelection.setText("Multiple Selection");
      }
    });

    /*
     *  To obtain a list of the selected row items of a JavaFX TableView, you call the 
     *  SelectionModel getSelectedItems() method. 
     */

    Button buttonItems = new Button("Selected Items");
    buttonItems.setOnAction(e -> {
      ObservableList<Contact> selectedItems = selectionModel.getSelectedItems();
      for (Contact contact : selectedItems) {
        textArea.appendText(contact + "\n");
      }
      textArea.appendText("---\n");
    });

    /*
     * You can also just obtain a list of the indices of the selected rows, 
     * instead of the selected items themselves. 
     */

    Button buttonIndices = new Button("Selected Indices");
    buttonIndices.setOnAction(e -> {
      ObservableList<Integer> selectedIndices = selectionModel.getSelectedIndices();
      textArea.appendText("Indices: " + selectedIndices.toString() + "\n");
      textArea.appendText("---\n");
    });

    /*
     *  You can clear all selected rows and cells using the TableViewSelectionModel clearSelection() 
     *  method.
     */

    Button buttonClear = new Button("Clear");
    buttonClear.setOnAction(e -> {
      selectionModel.clearSelection();
      textArea.clear();
    });
    
    //    botonAnadir, botonModificar, botonBorrar, botonGuardar, botonCargar

    /*
     * Creamos botón añadir
     */
    Button botonAnadir = new Button("Añadir");
    botonAnadir.setOnAction(e -> {
      selectionModel.clearSelection();
      dialogoAnadir();
      textArea.clear();
      textArea.setText("Contacto añadido");
    });
    
    /*
     * Creamos botón modificar
     */
    Button botonModificar = new Button("Modificar");
    botonModificar.setOnAction(e -> {
      ObservableList<Contact> selectedItems = selectionModel.getSelectedItems();
      int indice = 0;
      for (Contact contact : selectedItems) {
        nombre = contact.getFirstName();
        apellido = contact.getLastName();
        telefono = contact.getPhoneNumber();
        indice = tableView.getItems().indexOf(contact);
      }
      dialogoModificar(nombre, apellido, telefono, indice);
      tableView.refresh();
    });
    
    
//    Button buttonIndices = new Button("Selected Indices");
//    buttonIndices.setOnAction(e -> {
//      ObservableList<Integer> selectedIndices = selectionModel.getSelectedIndices();
//      textArea.appendText("Indices: " + selectedIndices.toString() + "\n");
//      textArea.appendText("---\n");
//    });
    /*
     * Creamos botón Borrar
     */
    Button botonBorrar = new Button("Borrar");
    botonBorrar.setOnAction(e -> {
      ObservableList<Contact> selectedItems = selectionModel.getSelectedItems();
      for (Contact contact : selectedItems) {
        tableView.getItems().remove(contact);
      }
      tableView.refresh();
    });
    
    /*
     * Creamos botón Guardar
     */
    Button botonGuardar=new Button("Guardar");
    
    botonGuardar.setOnAction(e->{
      List<Contact> selectedItems = selectionModel.getSelectedItems();
      guardarFichero(selectedItems);
    });
    /*
     * Creamos botón Cargar
     */
    Button botonAbrir = new Button("Abrir");
    
    // It is possible to listen for selection changes in the TableViewSelectionModel

    ObservableList<Contact> selectedItems = selectionModel.getSelectedItems();

    selectedItems.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Contact>() {
      @Override
      public void onChanged(Change<? extends Contact> change) {
        System.out.println("Selection changed: " + change.getList());
        }
    });
    
    // Layout, scene and stage
    HBox hBox = new HBox(10, buttonPrint, buttonItems, buttonIndices, buttonSelection, buttonClear);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    HBox hBox2 = new HBox(10, botonAnadir, botonModificar, botonBorrar,botonGuardar,botonAbrir);
    hBox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    VBox root = new VBox(10, tableView, hBox, hBox2, textArea);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("TableView Example");
    primaryStage.show();
    
  }
  
  private void guardarFichero(List<Contact> selectedItems) {
    try {
      FileChooser fileChooser=new FileChooser();
      File fichDestino=fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
      BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fichDestino));
      for(int i=0;i<selectedItems.size();i++) {
        bw.write(selectedItems.get(i).getName());
        bw.write(selectedItems.get(i).getPhoneNumber());
        bw.newLine();
      }
      bw.close();
    }catch(IOException e) {
      Alert alerta=new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
      alerta.setTitle("Excepcion!!");
      alerta.setHeaderText("Error en el fichero!");
      alerta.setContentText("Error de entrada/salida del fichero");
      alerta.showAndWait();
      
    }
  }

  private void dialogoAnadir() {
    Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.setTitle("Añadir Contacto");
    dialog.setHeaderText("Introduce los datos para añadir un nuevo contacto.");

    // Poner los botones que queramos
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.CANCEL);
    // Create los fields y labels
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

    Label firstName = new Label("First Name: ");
    Label lastName = new Label("Last Name: ");
    Label phoneNumber = new Label ("Phone Number: ");
    
    TextField firstNameField = new TextField();
    TextField lastNameField = new TextField();
    TextField phoneNumberField = new TextField();
    
    grid.add(firstName, 0, 0);
    grid.add(lastName, 0, 1);
    grid.add(phoneNumber, 0, 2);
    grid.add(firstNameField, 1, 0);
    grid.add(lastNameField, 1, 1);
    grid.add(phoneNumberField, 1, 2);

    dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

    Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
      tableView.getItems().add(new Contact(firstNameField.getText(), lastNameField.getText(), phoneNumberField.getText()));
    }
  }
  
  private void dialogoModificar(String nombre, String apellido, String telefono, int indice) {
    Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.setTitle("Añadir Contacto");
    dialog.setHeaderText("Introduce los datos para añadir un nuevo contacto.");

    
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.CANCEL);

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

    Label firstName = new Label("First Name: ");
    Label lastName = new Label("Last Name: ");
    Label phoneNumber = new Label ("Phone Number: ");
    
    TextField firstNameField = new TextField(nombre);
    firstNameField.setPromptText("Nombre");
    TextField lastNameField = new TextField(apellido);
    lastNameField.setPromptText("Apellido");
    TextField phoneNumberField = new TextField(telefono);
    
    grid.add(firstName, 0, 0);
    grid.add(lastName, 0, 1);
    grid.add(phoneNumber, 0, 2);
    grid.add(firstNameField, 1, 0);
    grid.add(lastNameField, 1, 1);
    grid.add(phoneNumberField, 1, 2);

    dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

    Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
      tableView.getItems().get(indice).setFirstName(firstNameField.getText());
      tableView.getItems().get(indice).setLastName(lastNameField.getText());
      tableView.getItems().get(indice).setPhoneNumber(phoneNumberField.getText());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usa un observableList para cargar los datos del fichero, oviamente al leer el fichero deberías cargarlos en una colección (Arraylist).